# Split Start and End timestamp into two based on defined interval

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Time in & out for Employees. I want to split based on dynamic Interval condition

If Interval is 15:00

**Input**

```
EMP_ID  SWIPE_IN    SWIPE_OUT
4   2019-01-21 13:10:00.000 2019-01-21 15:45:00.000
```

**Desired output**

```
EMP_ID  SWIPE_IN    SWIPE_OUT
4   2019-01-21 13:10:00.000 2019-01-21 15:00:00.000
4   2019-01-21 15:00:00.000 2019-01-21 15:45:00.000
```

Comment: You need to add more details. It's unclear what your condition is. You split on a 30 min interval here, not a 15.

Comment: 15:00 is the Interval hour. . .  for this input time stamp should split into from 14:30 to 15:00 and 15:00 to 15:30

Comment: @scsimon I think the OP means the split has to happen at 15:00.

Comment: @vijaym Are `SWAPE_IN` and `SWAPE_OUT` always on the same date?

Comment: @Zhorov yes it ll be on same date

Comment: You need to clarify this question. It is entirely too vague. Here is place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Its straight forward. 15:00 is the condition. so i have to split the input record into two (before 15:00 as one record and after 15:00 as another record) like in the output. its not about regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
Declare @Interval Varchar(30) = '15:00'
Insert Into [TableName]
Select EMP_ID, CAST(Convert(Varchar, SWIPE_OUT, 23)+ ' ' + @Interval As DateTime), SWIPE_OUT
From [TableName]
Where SWIPE_OUT > CAST(Convert(Varchar, SWIPE_OUT, 23)+ ' ' + @Interval As DateTime) 

Update [TableName]
SET SWIPE_OUT = CAST(Convert(Varchar, SWIPE_OUT, 23)+ ' ' + @Interval As DateTime)
Where SWIPE_IN <> CAST(Convert(Varchar, SWIPE_OUT, 23)+ ' ' + @Interval As DateTime) 
AND SWIPE_OUT > CAST(Convert(Varchar, SWIPE_OUT, 23)+ ' ' + @Interval As DateTime)
```

Comment: thanks pavan. But its only giving record above 15:00. . . but i need one record before 15:00 and another after 15:00